# Swift SceneKit: SCNAudioPlayer completion block (didFinishPlayback) syntax?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm not sure why I can't work this out, but In the documentation for the SCNAudioPlayer class, there are 2 blocks used for playback about to start and playback being completed.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnaudioplayer/1522818-didfinishplayback

I routinely create and use closures but I can't seem to get this one working:

```
let player = SCNAudioPlayer(source: source)
player.didFinishPlayback({()->void in
//code here
})
```

Or variants of the same thing makes swift 3 complain.

I was thinking this might be a NSNotification strategy but it seems a complicated procedure for something seemingly simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to *call* `didFinishPlayback` like a *function*. But as your own reference link shows, it is a *variable* that you must *set*.

```
player.didFinishPlayback = { /* ... */ }
```